# Web performance and load test - https site

Tags: visual-studio-2015, web-testing

During the playback of a web performance and load test, Visual Studio reports error 401 (Unauthorized) on a https site. In the properties of the test I included my credentials. 
Is https supported with this type of project?

Comment: Yes, HTTPS is supported. Did you pass the correct credentials? There are several ways of supplying credentials to a web site. You might try recording with Fiddler to see how the web site works.

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have recorded scripts in the top ribbon menu of a webtest find Set Credentials icon and enter the right credentials there or...

Try generating your recorded script to code (On the left upper corner you have Generate to code icon) and then add

```
    this.UserName="enterusername";
    this.Password="enterpassword";
```

Like this:

```
     public override IEnumerator<WebTestRequest> GetRequestEnumerator()
    {
        this.UserName = "username";
        this.Password = "password";

         //code...
    }
```